# Proof of two properties of a simple math function

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, functions, voting-theory

I would like to define a function to evaluate the value for some entities which receive a number of "up"s ($\mathcal{u}$) and "down"s ($\mathcal{d}$). I devised the following function:

> $\mathcal{f}:
> \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
> \rightarrow\lbrack0,1]$ such that $t\geq0$
>
> $
> \mathcal{f}\left( u, d, t\right)  =\left\{
> \begin{array}
> [c]{lll}
> 0 &  & t=0\\
> \frac{u}{u+d+\frac{1}{t}} &  & \text{otherwise}
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $
>
> where $\mathcal{t}$ stands for the max value of $(\mathcal{u} + \mathcal{d})$ amongst the entities

I conjecture that the function satisfies the following properties:

- For two tuples $(\mathcal{u}_1, \mathcal{d}_1)$ and $(\mathcal{u}_2, \mathcal{d}_2)$, if $\frac{\mathcal{u}_1} {\mathcal{u_1} + \mathcal{d_1}} \ge \frac{\mathcal{u}_2} {\mathcal{u_2} + \mathcal{d_2}}$ then $\mathcal{f}(u_1, d_1, t) \ge \mathcal{f}(u_2, d_2, t)$.

As an example for $(\mathcal{u}_1, \mathcal{d}_1) = (10,0)$ and $(\mathcal{u}_2, \mathcal{d}_2) = (999,1)$, $\mathcal{t} = 1000$ and $\mathcal{f}(u_1, d_1, t) = 0.9999$ and  $\mathcal{f}(u_2, d_2, t) = 0.9989$.

- For two tuples $(\mathcal{u}_1, \mathcal{d}_1)$ and $(\mathcal{u}_2, \mathcal{d}_2)$, if $\frac{\mathcal{u}_1} {\mathcal{u_1} + \mathcal{d_1}} = \frac{\mathcal{u}_2} {\mathcal{u_2} + \mathcal{d_2}}$ and $( \mathcal{u_1} + \mathcal{d_1}) \ge ( \mathcal{u_2} + \mathcal{d_2})$then $\mathcal{f}(u_1, d_1, t) \ge \mathcal{f}(u_2, d_2, t)$.

As an example for $(\mathcal{u}_1, \mathcal{d}_1) = (45,5)$ and $(\mathcal{u}_2, \mathcal{d}_2) = (9,1)$, $\mathcal{t} = 50$ and $\mathcal{f}(u_1, d_1, t) = 0.8996$ and  $\mathcal{f}(u_2, d_2, t) = 0.8982$.

*Question:*
As the examples also confirm, I highly believe that the properties hold for the defined function but I'm yet to prove them. I'll appreciate any help on this manner.

Comment: A suggestion : last resort, if nothing else works, you may want to try a proof by induction as your domain is $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$. Start with $(0,0)$, show that the properties hold for $(0,1)$, then try to show that if the properties hold for $(0,n)$ they hold for $(0,n+1)$. Then show that if the properties hold for $(0,n)$, they hold for $(1,n)$. And finally that if they hold for $(n,n)$, they hold for $(n+1,n)$. That might be tedious and lengthy, but I would guess it is feasible. That's just a guess though...

Comment: Thanks so much for the idea. I've been mostly trying on a 'proof by contradiction' but haven't succeed in yet. I'm currently occupied with other stuff but I'll certainly take a look in near future.